# How to add a new collation to an AWS PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, collation

I am working on a new AWS PostgreSQL instance and only have 3 collation and character type options. These are C, POSIX and en_US.UTF-8.

I want to add English_United Kingdom.1252 but I get this error: could not get collation version for locale "English_United Kingdom": error code 87.

Is there a way I can find which values would create the desired collate? Would need to be able to use it with Encoding UTF8 as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can only define a collation in PostgreSQL if it exists on the underlying operating system. Obviously that one doesn't exist there.

Comment: So I have just found out that AWS is run on Linux machines? So it makes sense that English_United Kingdom.1252 is not present as that is a windows locale, @LaurenzAlbe. Do you know if there is a Linux version of English_United Kingdom.1252? Mainly worried about date data being changed when loaded into the database.

Comment: That would be `en_UK.UTF-8`. But the locale doesn't influence how data are interpreted, so you need not worry.